# Embed js, css, images into separate assembly to read from asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, embedded-resource

I'd like to create a class library project where embed resources like js, css and maybe image files.
I would compile it and copy the dll into the bin folder of my web site to include the resources into my pages with GetWebResourceUrl.

I tried with an assembly that have no .cs files, but it doesn't seem to work, I can't see the namespace of the assembly in the web project.

Is it possible doing this?
Someone could provide a small tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the best way to embed the files like js , css and ... to dll is to select the embedded resources in build action of file property. take a look at this:

http://hasantechno.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-embedding-resources-image-css.html

by the way if you want to forbid any kind of unknown requests(out of you web site) to navigate the contents.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reduce the loading time, serve the media files as static content, as example over nginx.

Comment: Sorry, I would do it like that. Thanks.